# Installation of VTK with Visual Studio Community 2022 on Windows 10

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, vtk

I literally followed the procedure on the following website [Building VTK using Visual Studio on Windows](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/blob/master/Documentation/dev/build_windows_vs.md#building-vtk-using-visual-studio-on-windows)
I used CMake and Visual Studio Community 2022.
I downloaded the VTK source code into the "src" folder. After the buildind phase the "bin" folder was populated with the VTK library (.dll).
I tested the VTK library installation using the example suggested in the procedure.The executable (.exe) file was generated. If I click on such a file the expected picture pops up. If I try to run the test from Visual Studio I get the following error message "The code execution cannot proceed because vtkRenderingOpenGL2-9.2.dll was not found. Reinstallingthe program may fix this problem"
I am not clear about which program should be reinstalled. Is it Visual Studio, or VTK, or the example test?
I looked for the .dll mentioned in the error message in the "bin" folder. Such a file is indeed missing.
Shall I install OpenGL or should it be included in VTK source code.
I searche for OpenGL on my PC. I could not find it apart deom a subfolder of VTK "utility" that seems to have built a VTK solution and project for OpenGL but no .dll

I would appreciate some help. I am a physicist with some s/w development experience (mostly with MatLab).

Thank you in advance.

[image: Recorded mai steps of VTK installation and testing]

I have to use VTK for a project aimed at streamlining the process of designing implants for skull defect restoration. I need 3D visualization capability.
C++ has been imposed as the development language.
I chose Visual Studio Community 2022 (the latest) as my IDE.
My main project, developed through Visual Studio, should be able to use the runtime VTK library.

Comment: The warning you see is not important at all. It just says your CMake is newer than expected. The reason for that is the developers have to support many versions of CMake especially in the case of people using enterprise versions of linux which may have a several year old CMake in the package management.

Comment: ***The code execution cannot proceed because vtkRenderingOpenGL2-9.2.dll was not found.*** You need to copy the debug VTK dlls to the same folder as your debug executable and the release dlls to the same folder as your release executable or set the `PATH` environment variable. This Microsoft documentation explains how your windows OS searches for dlls and what your requirements are as a developer to help the OS find the correct dll: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-unpackaged-apps

Comment: There is a discrepancy between the online installation procedure I followed (named in my initial post) and the installation on my Windows PC.

Comment: According to the online procedure, at the end of Visual Studio building step of project ALL_BUILD, a folder named VTK<latest-version> containing a "build" directory with all the dll, should have been created inside "Program FIles". Unluckily Visual Studio building process does not create such directory at all. What am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: ***should have been created inside "Program FIles".*** That won't happen. There is an `INSTALL` target that may try to do that but your modern OS will prevent it because of `UAC`

Comment: I created a folder named VTK inside C:\Program Files  and I changed the access-writes  of such a folder so that  the INSTALL project does not complain.  I am not sure about how to set the VTK-DIR field in CMake  to configure and generate the example. The online procedure suggests:   C:/Program Files/VTK/lib/cmake/vtk-9.2       Shouldn't it be  C:\Program Files\VTK\bin ?      Anyway, regardless of the content of this field when I try to run with Visual Studio I get a lot of errors regarding missing dll. I do not know the workaround.

Comment: Does anybody have a procedure to install VTK with Visual Studio Community 2022 that  works?   I suspect the online one I found is not  updated to the lasted VS release   Thank you

Comment: When you get the error message in CMake that tells you about `VTK_DIR` do exactly what it says. This is one of the most helpful error messages I have seen as a programmer.

Comment: ***Does anybody have a procedure to install VTK with Visual Studio Community 2022 that works?*** I build VTK from source, don't use the INSTALL target at all. Then point `VTK_DIR` to the build folder of vtk. This has worked fine for me in many versions of VTK and Visual Studio since I started using VTK at work in 2008. With that said to run your VTK application the required dlls need to be in the `PATH` environment variable, or the same folder containing your executable or one of the other dozen ways windows uses to find dlls that are given in the documentation I linked on the second comment

Comment: ***"The code execution cannot proceed because vtkRenderingOpenGL2-9.2.dll was not found.*** Is a very easy problem to fix and has nothing to do with `VTK_DIR` or specifically `C:\Program Files\VTK` as the dlls don't need to be in this folder specifically. Windows does not look there unless you tell it to do so which is no different from any other folder.

Comment: Thank you.   Did you use Visual Studio Community 2022 with C++ to build vtk?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254356/discussion-between-mauede-and-drescherjm).

Comment: The problem was solved when IT changed my access rights to the Program Files folder.

Comment: I did run the INSTALL project.

Comment: I think the key for you to understand is with or without running the INSTALL target to solve the "vtkRenderingOpenGL2-9.2.dll was not found." problem you either need to set your `PATH` environment variable or copy the dlls the same folder as your executable. Neither of these steps are done for you.  The INSTALL target does not do this for you. You need to do these steps yourself.

Comment: I generally avoid the INSTALL target because I use multiple versions of msvc and multiple vtk builds as I have developed with VTK on windows since 2008 at work. I have a half dozen projects that use vtk. Some of which were developed recently but others were developed over a decade ago.

Comment: I appended the path to the "dll" folder to the environment variable PATH. I meant to place my VTK folder inside the System Filesas suggested in the